# Code Completion Plugin for Struts in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, struts2, eclipse-plugin

I've moved on from JSF to Struts in order to get a more rounded understanding of the two frameworks. In JSF when I created an XHTML file and inserted the necessary JSF tag libraries, like so:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

I was able to get code completion. For example - it could tell me what variables were readable/writable from that particular class attached to that bean - helpful when you think you have correctly created them but haven't. I was wondering if **Struts** has an equivalent?

For example, in my login screen I have the following:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="User/Login.action">first example</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a library or plugin that could be added that would automatically complete this if necessary.

Cheers

Comment: no such plugin is there, though Net-beans and IntelliJ provide support for Struts2.Can you give more details what exactly you are looking for

Comment: what i mean is say i declare another action (ToBinary) in the struts.xml file which has a result pages/decimalToBinary.jsp. Is there a plugin that could tell me, using the shortcut Ctrl+Spacebar, the actions available? Much like if in java if you typed 'Map' then hit the shortcut it would list the classes that implement that interface.

Comment: well i guess not up to this point but `IntelliJ` and Netbeans provides support.I have not used both so can not comment about there support

Comment: Thats unfortunate because I'm stuck with Eclipse - oh well just need to be careful about approaching it then - Thanks!

Comment: You're asking for completion on actions in raw HTML tags? IntelliJ won't do that, not sure about MyEclipse. Actual S2 tags do have a fair amount of completion in IntelliJ, again not sure about MyEclipse. AFAIK MyEclipse is the only Eclipse environment that has decent S2 support. I don't understand the concept of "stuck on Eclipse", though.

Comment: I didn't mean it like Eclipses is a bad thing - just in my office we use Eclipse over say Netbeans and it would seem pointless to learn how to use a new IDE just for this capability, assuming it had it

Comment: @Katana24: I am using eclipse from very first day and working with Struts2 from so long and honestly never felt the need for any kind of plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

put this on the head of your page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```

Here is the reference for all tag [Tag Reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tag-reference.html)

Btw. Welcome to Struts2.

Comment: good start but is there a way to reference variables in particular classes? Like in JSF you had to have a proper getter and setter method on a variable to read/write to it.